# Change WPF control property on one theme only

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, themes, listviewitem

I know this is a little petty, but... On Windows 7, the default foreground color for ListViewItems is, for whatever reason, dark blue.  This confuses and infuriates me.  I would like to make my ListViewItems have black text.  But if I set my TextBlocks in the DataTemplate to have Foreground="Black", then it looks weird on Windows XP, since the Foreground of the selected item is supposed to be White on XP; with Foreground="Black" it's quite hard to read.   Is there some way I can set the Foreground to Black only on the Aero theme and not on the other themes?

Answer (score 0):

What about if someone uses a theme that you have not tested? You cannot control every single theme.
I suggest you to build your own ControlTemplate to achieve your desired visualization. In this way your controls will be displayed in the same way in all situations.

Comment: I really don't see how that's relevant.  I'm not trying to control every single theme.  I'm only trying to control one theme: the one the majority of my users will see.